# Instance of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a program that used async task everytime the button is clicked... I dont want to keep typing the WHOLE AsyncTask everytime it is clicked.. That will be to tedious. What is a better way i can do this? 
Here is some source code.

```
  new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>(){

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {                 
             Thread.sleep(1000);             
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                         
                e.printStackTrace();             
                    }            
                    return null;
            }
            @Override         
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
                    text1.setText("Nice to meet you "+name);
                    dismissDialog(typeBar);
                     }


                @Override        
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            typeBar = 0;
        showDialog(typeBar);

        }

        }.execute((Void)null);

        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new class that extends AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
    }
}
```

Then whereever you need it just do this:

```
new MyTask.execute();
```

Thats it! Have fun!

Comment: Okay Thanks that sounds like what im looking for. Im going to implement that. But one more question.  I want my text to change constantly in the AsyncTask class... Would i hhave to create a method in the Async class for each time i want to change the textView? That will be extremely tedious.

Comment: @theITRanger22 Can you explain a little more why you do want to modify the text?

Comment: @olamotee Okay So the Program uses the asynTask to display progress dialog first... Then a textView... The user then enters some info, and clicks a button and the textViewchanges.... And this happens all throughout the program..I just want to find a easier way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a public or private class.  You can then reference/instantiate it based on the name of the newly made class.